# Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault

Tried to trace, but did not find a reason why the following code is giving "Access violation" in VC++, and segmentation fault in gcc..

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node
{
    std::string data;
    vector <struct node*> child;
}NODE, *PNODE;

int main()
{
    PNODE head;
    head = (PNODE) malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    head->data.assign("hi");

    printf("data %s", head->data.c_str());
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Your headers are missing at the top

Comment: `vector  child;` is invalid.

Comment: `malloc` allocates memory; it doesn't construct objects. Your code is very broken.

Comment: That's not C++; that's not even "C with classes." I suggest you pick up a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `new` rather than `malloc` to create C++ objects on the heap.

The following:

```
head = (PNODE) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

should read

```
head = new NODE;
```

The reason `malloc()` doesn't work here is that it doesn't call object constructors.

Answer (score 12):

And why on earth do you think it should work?  You use `malloc`, rather than `new`, so no constructors are called, and everything you do accesses uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous answers.

I should add that it's best practice to avoid `using namespace` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c))

And in C++, avoid using C-like struct declaration :

```
typedef struct node
   {
       std::string data;
       vector  child;
   }NODE, *PNODE;
```

should be:

```
struct Node
{
    std::string data;
    std::vector<Node> child;
}
```

then:

```
Node head;
```

or:

```
Node* head = new Node;
```

If you are using c++, use `std::cout` instead of `printf`

There are c++ cast operator too : `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast`, `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/))